# JMeter Encoding issue

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract a value from http response which is in the
format "test/23|temp value"
and need to pass it in next request string body as "test%2F%7Ctemp+value"
I believe we are doing some form of encoding. how can we achieve this in JMeter ?
Appreciate if any one can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)

```
${__urlencode(test/23|temp value)}
```

it does [percent-encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) of the input and returns the result in the place where it's called in the runtime:

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)